# App Crashing Despite of Being ARC Enabled

Tags: objective-c, ios, debugging, automatic-ref-counting

I have been working on an iOS App for sometime now and its almost ready to submit. However, when I gave it to few people for testing purposes (running iOS 5)..they reported cases where the app crashes and the home screen is displayed on the phone OR a frozen app screen appears with no response whatsoever

The app is ARC enabled and Xcode shows no warnings. So, I'm relli tensed about what's going wrong. I have declared properties in the following fashion:

```
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *devCountLabel;

@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *splashView;
```

Likewise other properties are declared. Could anyone provide a solution? It is mainly a network based app and thus, CoreData usage is minimum.

PS: The App doesn't crash in the simulator, so I'm guessing it has something related to memory. And the crashes are random. So, repeating a set of steps to reproduce the crash doesn't help either.
For Eg. When I click a button, modalViewControllerAnimation results in normal case. Now this occurs as expected most of the time and freezes the app other times.

Comment: can you add crab logs as well?

Comment: crab logs? Are you talking about the stuff that comes on Console? Well..there's nothing there via the simulator.. :( :( I'll have to check via the Phone..

Comment: I guess @rishi is referring to CrashLog/s

Comment: ARC is great, but it's not magic; it doesn't make you immune to bugs and crashes.  I'm afraid we'll need more code to help you narrow this down.

Comment: Sure @zpasternack ..But I'm not sure of the origin of the crash. So I'm yet to figure the code out and paste it here. The crash logs show nothing.. :(

Comment: @proctr, connect the device on which the crash occurred to your Mac, open Xcode Organizer (Shift+Cmd+2), select the Devices tab, click on Device Logs under the device in the left panel and look for the logs of your app. Copy and paste here one of the logs.

Comment: If it helps, "command - shift - B" in Xcode will show you some potential memory problems in your code.

Comment: nothing at the analysis step (CMD+SHIFT+B)..I will post the logs soon though..that might help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crash logs will help, but here is my guess:

Interface Builder Outlet properties should be `weak`, so they become `nil` after they get released.

In your code their semantics is `assign` (it's by default, since you wrote `nonatomic` only), which is used for primitive types. And when it gets released, you get a dangling pointer, and when you use it, the app crashes.

Try this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *devCountLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *splashView;
```

Comment: As of Xcode 4.3, 'strong' is the default for property declarations without explicit ownership.  See [the docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.spelling.property).

Comment: @zpasternack Thanks for the heads up! Waiting for the logs then, so I could update my answer.

Comment: That's not true that IBOutlet properties **must** be weak.  It might be true that it's a *good* thing to do.  But, if you look at the UI code that Apple itself generates, IBOutlet properties are frequently `strong`, with explicit calls to nil them out in `viewDidUnload`.

Comment: @Nate, Xcode generates `strong` outlets only if your view is outside of your view controller’s view, because it may outlive the view controller’s view. If you place the view *inside* the view controller’s view, it generates `weak` outlet. [Managing the Lifetimes of Objects from Nib Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW6)

Comment: I changed all my IBOutlets to weak attribute and the crashing isn't occurring FOR NOW..Hope it stays that way.

Comment: @StanislavYaglo, sorry, you're still wrong.  Your link states that strong references are not **needed** inside your view controller's view.  That's not the same as the incorrect statement you made in your answer, where you said the `IBOutlet` properties **must** be weak.  Not to mention, you're still wrong about how Xcode generates properties.  I just tested it.  Right-click on a subview of the view controller's main view, drag a new reference to the view controller's .h file, and a **strong** property is generated.  Run the app, and there is no memory leak.

Comment: @Nate, okay. 1. English is not my native language, so I may mix should and must sometimes (in my native language must does not mean “kill yourself, but do it”). Sorry for that. 2. Read the docs again. weak for subviews, strong for top level objects. I don't know which version of Xcode you are using, but I always check and test stuff before posting. It is not about leaks, it's about when you need the objects. Of course it will not leak if you release it manually (by setting it to nil).

Comment: @StanislavYaglo, thank you for the correction.  *Should* is much better than *must*.  The real problem was that his/her code used `assign`.  If they used `strong`, there would have been no crash.  Xcode 4.2 is still generating `strong` properties when you connect an IBOutlet as I described.  And again, there's nothing incorrect about that, either with respect to a memory leak **or** an object not being available when needed **or** a dangling pointer.  It's just not *needed*.